# Custom indicator function for quantstrat

Tags: r, quantstrat

I'm having trouble writing a custom indicator function for use with `quanstrat::add.indicator`

Error:

```
Error in inherits(x, "xts") : object 'price' not found
```

My code:

```
library(quantstrat)
symbols<-getSymbols("USD/EUR",src="oanda")
strat<-acct<-portfolio<-"tempTest"
initEq<-1000

initDate <- '2009-12-31'
currency("USD")
exchange_rate(symbols, currency="USD")
rm.strat(strat) # remove portfolio, account, orderbook if re-run
initPortf(name=portfolio, symbols, initDate=Sys.Date())
initAcct(name=acct, portfolios=portfolio,initDate=Sys.Date(), initEq=initEq)
initOrders(portfolio=portfolio, initDate=Sys.Date())
strategy(strat, store=TRUE)

colnames(USDEUR)<-"Close"
#################################################################################################

RSI.lagged<-function(lag=1,n=2,...){
  RSI <- RSI(price)
  RSI <- lag(RSI, lag)
  out <- RSI$rsi
  colnames(out) <- "rsi"
  return(out)
}

########RSI indicator
####THIS IS LAGGED TO PREVENT FOREKNOWLEDGE
add.indicator(strat, name="RSI.lagged", arguments=list(price = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=2), label="rsiIndLagged")
test <- applyIndicators(strat, mktdata=USDEUR)
```

After adding the parameter `price` to the RSI.lagged function eg `RSI.lagged<-function(lag=1,n=2,price,...)` I get the error:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "rsi") : attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

Comment: Where is the `add.indicator` function? The only function you show code for is `RSI.lagged` (and if you want it to use `price` inside it then you should pass in an argument named `price`), but you don't show any code that calls it.

Comment: My apologies, `library(quantstrat)` is the required library. I have edited my code to include this.

Comment: I'm still confused---I believe you responded to the first 5 words of my comment, but ignored the other 40 words. Or am I missing something else?

Comment: I was under the impression that the `...` meant that all arguments (like price), which are supplied in `add.indicator` `arguments` parameter  would be magically passed to the function RSI.lagged. Am I misunderstanding the `...` meaning somehow?

Comment: You're not using the `...` argument of `add.indicator` at all. It has both an `arguments` parameter (which you are using) and a `...` parameter which you aren't using... though the documentation doesn't make the difference between the two very clear.

Comment: However, you are misunderstanding `...` in `RSI.lagged`. The only reason a function `foo` should have `...` in its definition is if `foo` will do nothing to the `...` arguments except pass them to another function - whatever they may be. Your `RSI.lagged` function is specifically using an argument named `price`, so `price` should be a formal, named argument of `RSI.lagged`.

Comment: To be clear, I think it will work if you replace `...` with `price` in your definition of `RSI.lagged`. Haven't tested though...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation- I attempted to pass `price` with no luck. (See error above)

Comment: Well, what's the point of your `colnames(out) <- "rsi"` line? Vectors don't have column names, so either delete that line or coerce `rsi` to a 1-column data frame. Maybe you want to return a vector. Or maybe you want to return `RSI["rsi"]`.

Comment: Cool, could you post comments 5 & 6 as an answer, with some links to documentation so I can accept it and resolve the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were trying to access the name of a column that does not exist.  Try this instead to get your indicator to work:

```
RSI.lagged<-function(price, lag=1,n=2,...){
  # Stick in a browser to see your problem more clearly:
  # browser()
  rsi <- RSI(price)
  rsi <- lag(rsi, lag)
  # This column name does not exist: "rsi".  The name of the column gets the default "EMA"
  # tail(rsi)
  #                 EMA
  # 2017-11-04 63.48806
  # 2017-11-05 66.43532
  # 2017-11-06 64.41188
  # 2017-11-07 66.02659
  # 2017-11-08 67.96394
  # 2017-11-09 66.08134
  colnames(rsi) <- "rsi"
  return(out)
}
```

(Aside, also strongly suggest you do not try using Oanda data to backtest with,as the prices aren't "real"; they are a weighted average price for each day. See:  [Exact time stamp on quantmod currency (FX) data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41275039/exact-time-stamp-on-quantmod-currency-fx-data/41361054#41361054))

Comment: WOW That last line is incredibly important..... Thanks so much for pointing that out!